# Error with opening running flask server(error 404)

Tags: python, flask, web, logging

The point of my website is to add a number and that number gets inserted into my mysql table. But my flask server despite running is showing error 404 when I open the flask server website.

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/app.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
def insertnumber(n):
    import mysql.connector as sql
    mycon = sql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",password = "devkar@nam",database = "web")
    cur = mycon.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into numinf values(%s)"%(n))
    mycon.commit()
    cur.close()
    mycon.close()

@app.route('/script.py', methods=['POST'])
def add_number():
    number = request.form['number']
    try:
        insertnumber(number)
        logging.info(f"Number {number} saved")
        return 'Number saved!'
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error saving number: {str(e)}")
        return 'Error saving number'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have the following error in my log files:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
2023-06-19 07:17:42,496 INFO: [33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
2023-06-19 07:17:52,933 INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2023 07:17:52] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
2023-06-19 07:17:52,993 INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2023 07:17:52] "[33mGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

The point of my website is to add a number and that number gets inserted into my mysql table. But my flask server despite running is showing error 404 when I open the flask server website. I am extremely new to this so please spare mercy.

Comment: None of the URLs accessed matches your route.

Comment: 404 means that your page has not been found, this is because you haven't defined any routes that match the URL you are looking for. `@app.route("/")` is the route you are accessing.  Have a look at the minimal application in the quickstart guide: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/